# grep - List out items ending with '(' from the file

Tags: grep

I have a list and need to extract the below patterns

- funcName(
- funcNameOther(

all function names ending with '( succeeded by a newline'

Answer (score 0):

`egrep -o '.*\($'` does the trick for me, if that's what you're looking after.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '($'  file
```

If that doesn't do what you want, provide some more useful sample input and expected output.

Comment: WinBase.h found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v5.0\Include is the input file. Need to extract all the function names from it like DecodePointer (, EncodeSystemPointer (, DecodeSystemPointer (

Comment: No. Edit your question to show representative sample input and expected output.